# Is there a maximal (or maximal Tychonoff) non normal space?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, lattice-theory

Is there a maximal (or maximal Tychonoff) non normal space? In "A Problem of Set-Teoretic Topology" the existence of a maximal Tychonoff space is asserted. Also there exists a perfectly normal maximal spaces (it suffices to consider a maximal topology on a countable set). Maximal topology means a maximal topology on a set which is devoid of isolated points. Maximal $\cal{P}$ space is a maximal space which hes the property $\cal{P}$ and is devoid of isolated points. 
If there is a relative article I would be grateful  introduce it.

Comment: Dear @Vahideh: Please do not use the deprecated tag 'topology'. The tag 'gn.general-topology' is sufficient.

Comment: Ok dear.But why I do it?

Comment: The use of certain tags, such as 'topology', is discouraged because the tags are not specific enough or because they duplicate other tags.

Answer (score 2):

Malykhin constructed a consistent example of a Tychonoff non-normal maximal space in this paper:

V. I. Malykhin, "Extremally disconnected and similar groups", Soviet Math. Dokl. 16 (1975), 21–25.